Running cron job only on 1 task instance in a multi instance AWS ECS Fargate container
I would like to run a cron job which runs everyday and do some operation. Now my nodejs server has 4 instances/tasks running simultaneously to handle the load. How can i ensure that my cron job is only picked up by a single instance/task so that the operation doesn't get duplicated.

make that cron job as a single task, and that task was triggered by Amazon EventBridge Scheduler. once the cron job complete, the task itself should clean up by terminating the task

As mentioned above, run the cron job as a separate ECS Task. Make it an ECS Scheduled Task instead of an ECS Service.
